# JQuery UI autocomplete not working in MVC View

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm thinking of putting an autocomplete feature for one of my input fields in Asp.net view so I tried out the example from Jquery UI and pasted the code inside one of the .cshtml views:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = ["Boston Celtics", "Chicago Bulls", "Miami Heat", "Orlando Magic", "Atlanta Hawks"];
$("#seed_one").autocomplete({source:data});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="seed_one" type="text" name="seed_one" />
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I run the application and start typing something in the input field, no suggestions show up. What's the problem with the code?

Comment: Check your browser console to see you have any script errors. Your code works fine http://jsbin.com/livajenuco/edit?html,js,output

Comment: this code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/ajays871/j6p0ogjt/

Comment: put the `document.ready` script at the end of your `body` tag

Comment: I'm getting this error in Chrome debug: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Create:151)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)

Comment: look at your jquery version, that's an old one isn't it? are you loading another jquery? it's either wrong version or you are calling it too early.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you download both jQuery and jQuery UI instead of using its CDN. The problem with using the latest jQuery version is that you never know what version it's, or if it's compatible with the current jQuery UI version.

By using the latest version URL of jQuery, its version will be changed from time to time, causing breaking changes sometimes, or generating incompatibilities with external libraries (such as jQuery UI).

Also, here's a working fiddle for the autocomplete:
https://jsfiddle.net/zymh9xk9/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = ["Boston Celtics", "Chicago Bulls", "Miami Heat", "Orlando Magic", "Atlanta Hawks"];
  $("#seed_one").autocomplete({source:data});
});
```

Download the latest production (stable) version of jQuery here:
https://jquery.com/download/

As well as jQuery UI:
https://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: I'm still getting the error saying that autocomplete is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymus>. Here is a screenshot of the error taken in Chrome: [link](http://prntscr.com/dvlwhm)

Comment: Are you calling jQuery UI right after jQuery itself? This error only occurs when your jQuery UI isn't loading. You can try to inspect your page and check if your files are being loaded in your  'Element' tab (if you're using Google Chrome).

Comment: Took a look at the Element tab. Seems like JQuery is loaded, but JQuery UI is not. Why? I've installed the JQuery Ui through Bower and linked it right after linking JQuery like this: <script src="~/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Here is the screenshot of Element tab: [link](http://prntscr.com/dvlz9w)

Comment: Libraries installed with bower are located in the bower components folder: bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js. If your current file is a sibling of bower_components folder, you can use the above source as the absolute path for your jQuery UI file.

Comment: so you've got both the cdn jquery UI link (in your html above), and a local link to it as well? this would be as issue i'd think?

Comment: you can also check the Sources tab in chrome devtools (make sure you expand the 'navigator' tab on the left side) to see what's been loaded from anywhere in the web app.